# Having an issue with Multiple middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to process 2 middleware before routing it to controller. Laravel won't give me an error on the following code but it only processes the 1st middleware '*CheckReferer*' and won't process the 2nd middleware '*CheckCart*'. It process the 1st middleware even if you change the sequence (e.g 'CheckCart', 'CheckReferer').

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix($language)->middleware('CheckReferer', 'CheckCart')->group(function() {

     Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex')->name('home');

});
```

**CheckReferer.php (Middleware)**

```
class CheckReferer
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $Referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;

        if($Referer != null) {
            $url_parsed = parse_url($Referer);

            if ($url_parsed['host'] == 'www.example.com') {

                $Referer = true;
                Session::put('Referer', $Referer);

            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

**CheckCart.php (Middleware)**

```
class CheckCart
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $oldCart = Session::has('Cart') ? Session::get('Cart') : null;

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass them as array...

```
Route::prefix($language)->middleware(['CheckReferer', 'CheckCart'])->group(function() {

     Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex')->name('home');

});
```